# unable to access flask with postman

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, backend

I am following the flask quickstart to create a python server so that I can send data from postman to the server. However, when I run the code using "python main.py", nothing happens in the command line. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from server import analyzeWeaknesses

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/analyzeWeaknesses', methods=['POST'])
def WeaknessAnalysis():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        analyzeWeaknesses(request.data)
        return {"status":"success"}
    else:
        error = 'Unable to access data!'
```

analyzeWeaknesses simply takes in an input and does an analysis of it and outputs integers. I would like this output to be also returned to postman. **Desired outcome** Postman to for python input and then receive its output

Comment: The recommended way to start Flask apps is `flask run`, by the way

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the main function. Add this at the bottom of your code-

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run()
```